# Explaining advanced string formatting python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I'm trying to understand how [this answer on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193447) works, turning integers into french licence plates with the following code:

```
lambda n:f"%c%c-{n%1000:03}-%c%c"%(*(65+n//1000//26**i%26for i in[3,2,1,0]),)
```

I understand `'%c'` with `65 + n` on a `% 26` number to get the letters, and I understand `% 1000 : 03` for getting `3-0` padded numbers up to `999`. However I can't find anything on the following:

- the use of two forward slashes here
- the effect of the `{ }` brackets in the string

Explanations would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `//` is for integer division (it only keeps the integer part of a division operation result, similar to `int(n/m)`).

Example:

```
>>> n, m = 10, 7
>>> n / m
1.4285714285714286
>>> n // m
1
```

The `{}` in f-strings is used to evaluate an expression from within the string itself.

Example:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> print(f"x^2 = {x**2}")
x^2 = 25
```

Answer (score 2):

The double slashes (`//`) are integer division. Back in Python2 the `/` was ambiguous. It meant different things, depending on the types on the two sides. This caused a fair amount of confusion, so in Python3 it has been split to `/` and `//`, where `/` is always standard division, if you run `5/3` it will always be 1.66..., no matter if 5 and 3 are ints or floats. Meanwhile `//` is always integer division, which divides than floors the number. (so `3.4 // 1.2` is `2`)

`f'...{expression}...'` is a so called f-string. It takes the the value in the `{}` brackets, and formats it in place. It's similar `'...{}...'.format(expression)`. It's tricky because the example uses both f strings and % formatting.